# initialise a hash's keys with an array

Tags: perl

I need to initialize a hash of hashes. The way I do it is below, is there a more elegant way to do it?

```
$biggest_word_size = 0;
foreach $sig (@signals) 
    {
    $sigs->{$sig} = "None";
    $biggest_word_size = 
        ( $biggest_word_size > length($sig) ) ? $biggest_word_size : length($sig) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To be honest, for what you want, this is pretty much as elegant as you want. You can do it in a slightly more idiomatic way, but **why**? It's perfectly readable and concise enough
2. If the size of your array is not too large, and you don't care about squeezing every last ounce of performane, you can do those 2 tasks separately in a slightly more idiomatic way (at the cost of scanning the array twice):

   ```
    use List::Util qw(max);
    my $sigs = { map {$_ => 'None'} @signals };
    my $biggest_word_size = max map {length} @signals;
   ```

Comment: A bit of sugar: `max map length, @signals`.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Util qw[max];
my $biggest_word_size = 0;
my $sigs = { map { 
    $biggest_word_size = max($biggest_word_size, length $_);
    $_ => 'None' } @signals };
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you ignore the `$biggest_word_size` bit, to initialise a hashref from an array can be

```
my $sigs = { map { $_ => 'None' } @signals };
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but I still need the $biggest_word_size... is there a built in function for hashes returning the biggest word or something similar (like keys for example) ?

Comment: my @sorted = sort{ length($a) <=> length($b) } keys %$sigs;
my $biggest_word_size = length($sorted[-1]);

Answer (score 0):

```
@signals = sort{ length($a) <=> length($b) } @signals;
my $sigs = { map { $_ => 'None' } @signals };
my $biggest_word_size = length($signals[-1]);
```

I would use a sort to achieve this.